Fixing the consensus algorithm code for ROS Noetic
The Python script below is about an implementation of the consensus algorithm (rendez-vous) using static Metropolis weights for Turtlesim in ROS Noetic, run in Ubuntu 20.04 OS.
The issue is that the turtles are not moving after spawned. I tried to debug to see some problems (#debug lines in the code below). When I run it, it seems that it keeps stuck endlessly in the console executing
rospy.loginfo("Received pose for turtle{}: {}".format(index+1, position))

I do not know why is this happening. What I know is that the methods for generate adjacent matrix, compute the consensus algorithm, the check convergence and the spawn turtles are correct.
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
from turtlesim.msg import Pose
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from std_msgs.msg import String
from turtlesim.srv import Spawn
import random
import numpy as np
import math
import threading

class TurtleRendezvous:
    def __init__(self, num_robots):
        rospy.init_node('turtle_rendezvous', anonymous=True)
        self.num_robots = num_robots
        self.turtle_positions = {} #[]       
        self.turtle_mean_position = []
        
        self.previous_positions = []
        self.next_positions = []
        
        self.adjacency_matrix = self.generate_adjacency_matrix()
        self.robot_subs = []
        self.vel_pubs = []
        self.tolerance = 0.1
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(20)
        
    def generate_pub_sub(self):    
        for i in range(self.num_robots):          
            sub = rospy.Subscriber('/turtle0{}'.format(i+1) + '/pose', Pose, self.pose_callback, callback_args=i)
            vel_pub = rospy.Publisher('/turtle0{}'.format(i+1) + '/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
            self.robot_subs.append(sub)
            self.vel_pubs.append(vel_pub)    
        
    def generate_adjacency_matrix(self):
        z2_matrix = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(self.num_robots, self.num_robots))

        # Calculate adjacency matrix, first making it symmetric
        adjacency_matrix = ((z2_matrix)@(z2_matrix.transpose())) % 2
    
        # Fill diagonal with zeros (since it is an adjacency matrix)
        np.fill_diagonal(adjacency_matrix, 0)

        # Ensure each row has at least one 1 (ensure that every robot is not isolated)
        for i in range(num_robots):
            if np.sum(adjacency_matrix[i]) == 0:  # If the row has all zeros
                # Choose a random column index and set it to 1
                j = np.random.randint(0, num_robots)
                while (j==i):
                    j = np.random.randint(0, num_robots)
                adjacency_matrix[i, j] = 1
                adjacency_matrix[j, i] = 1

        return adjacency_matrix

    def pose_callback(self, data, index):
        position = [data.x, data.y]
        
        #debug
        rospy.loginfo("Received pose for turtle{}: {}".format(index+1, position))
        
        self.turtle_positions[index] = position
        #self.turtle_positions.append(position)
    
    def consensus_algorithm(self):
        self.next_positions = []
        for i in range(self.num_robots):
            x_sum = 0
            y_sum = 0
            weight_sum = 0
            for j in range(self.num_robots):
                if (j!=i) and (self.adjacency_matrix[i][j]==1):  # Exclude self-connections
                    weight = 1 / (1 + max(np.count_nonzero(self.adjacency_matrix[i]), np.count_nonzero(self.adjacency_matrix[j])))
                    x_sum += weight * self.previous_positions[j][0]
                    y_sum += weight * self.previous_positions[j][1]
                    weight_sum += weight
            next_x = x_sum + (1-weight_sum)*self.previous_positions[i][0]
            next_y = y_sum + (1-weight_sum)*self.previous_positions[i][1]
            self.next_positions.append([next_x, next_y])
        
        #debug
        rospy.loginfo("Next positions calculated: {}".format(self.next_positions))
        
        return self.next_positions
    
    def move_turtle(self, index):
        vel_msg = Twist()
        kv = 1.5
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            vel_msg.linear.x = kv* (math.cos(0)*(self.next_positions[index][0]-self.previous_positions[index][0]) +math.sin(0)*(self.next_positions[index][1]-self.previous_positions[index][1]))  
            vel_msg.linear.y = kv* (-math.sin(0)*(self.next_positions[index][0]-self.previous_positions[index][0]) +math.cos(0)*(self.next_positions[index][1]-self.previous_positions[index][1]))
            
            #debug
            rospy.loginfo("Publishing velocity command for turtle{}".format(index+1))
            
            self.vel_pubs[index].publish(vel_msg)
            self.rate.sleep()

    def check_convergence(self):
        for i in range(self.num_robots):
            if math.sqrt((self.next_positions[i][0] - self.turtle_mean_position[-1][0]) ** 2 + (self.next_positions[i][1] - self.turtle_mean_position[-1][1]) ** 2) > self.tolerance:
                return False
        return True

    def spawn_turtles_randomly(self):
        x_mean = 0
        y_mean = 0
    
        for i in range(self.num_robots):
            x = random.uniform(1, 10)
            y = random.uniform(1, 10)
            rospy.wait_for_service('/spawn')
            x_mean = (i*x_mean + x)/(i+1)
            y_mean = (i*y_mean + x)/(i+1)
            try:
                spawn_turtle = rospy.ServiceProxy('/spawn', Spawn)
                spawn_turtle(x, y, 0, '/turtle0{}'.format(i+1))
                rospy.loginfo("Spawned turtle 'turtle0{}' at position ({}, {}) with theta 0 degrees".format(i+1, x, y))
                self.turtle_positions[i] = (x, y) 
                #self.turtle_positions.append((x, y))
                self.turtle_mean_position.append((x_mean, y_mean))
            except rospy.ServiceException as e:
                rospy.logerr("Spawn service call failed: {}".format(e))

    def run(self):
        rospy.loginfo("Spawning turtles...")
        self.generate_pub_sub()
        self.spawn_turtles_randomly()
        rospy.loginfo("Adjacency matrix generated: ")
        A = self.generate_adjacency_matrix()
        for i in range(self.num_robots):
            rospy.loginfo(A[i])
        rospy.loginfo("Starting Turtle Rendezvous Algorithm...")
        
        #self.previous_positions = self.turtle_positions
                
        # Wait until pose information for all turtles is received
        #while len(self.turtle_positions) < self.num_robots and not rospy.is_shutdown():
         #   rospy.logwarn("Waiting for pose information from all turtles...")
          #  self.rate.sleep()
            
        #rospy.sleep(1)
             
        '''
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            threads = []
            for i in range(self.num_robots):
                self.next_positions = self.consensus_algorithm(self.previous_positions)
                self.previous_positions = self.next_positions
                t = threading.Thread(target=self.move_turtle, args=(i, self.previous_positions[i], self.next_positions[i]))
                threads.append(t)
                t.start()

            # Wait for all threads to finish
            for t in threads: t.join()
               
            #next_positions = self.consensus_algorithm()
            #self.move_turtles(next_positions)
            
            if self.check_convergence(self.next_positions):
                rospy.loginfo("Convergence achieved!")
                break
            self.rate.sleep()
        '''
        
        '''
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            self.next_positions = self.consensus_algorithm()
            threads = [threading.Thread(target=self.move_turtle, args=(i)) for i in range(self.num_robots)]
            for t in threads:
                t.start()
            for t in threads:
                t.join()
            if self.check_convergence():
                rospy.loginfo("Convergence achieved!")
                break
            self.rate.sleep()
        '''
        
        # From here, it is stuck in the execution.
        self.previous_positions = list(self.turtle_positions.values())
        
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            self.next_positions = self.consensus_algorithm()
            for i in range(self.num_robots):
                self.move_turtle(i)
            if self.check_convergence():
                rospy.loginfo("Convergence achieved!")
                break
            self.rate.sleep()
       
                    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        num_robots = int(input("Enter the number of robots: "))
        turtle_rendezvous = TurtleRendezvous(num_robots)
        turtle_rendezvous.run()
        rospy.spin() #
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass

```

